# Lost parameter names in TableAdapter generated Insert method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tableadapter, generated-code

I'm trying to generate a Insert method in a TableAdapter with a query like

```
INSERT INTO Status
                  (ScheduleID, StatusID, Name, Color)
VALUES     (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here Name is a string and the other are integers.
The generated signature however looks like this:

```
InsertQuery(int Color, string Param2, string Param3, string Param4)
```

Which does not match the query, either in name or order of parameter types.

How can this happen?
How can I be sure that Parameter2 is StatusID if I decide to change it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code(xml), change them according to it(open xml schema of your dataset and do that there). You can change their names to whatever you like.